# User: null does not have permission='CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE'

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I am trying to connect a simple paho client to artemis wildfly broker. I am getting this when I try to connect my client:
**WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt] (Thread-2 (activemq-netty-threads-164875171)) Error processing Control Packet, Disconnecting ClientAMQ119032: User: null does not have permission='CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE' on address $sys.mqtt.queue.qos2.JavaSample.**

I added an application user to wildfly, I gave him 'guest' as role, and in my standalone-full.xml, I found this:

```html
<security-setting name="#">
       <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
 </security-setting>
```

So I tried to connect my client with username and password (created as an application user in wildfly), but it doesn't work and can not connect to the broker.

Could you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known bug in the version of Artemis embedded in Wildfly.

I recommend you try using ActiveMQ Artemis standalone rather than embedded in Wildfly. The version in Wildfly is based on 1.5.x which has some bugs (specifically in relation to MQTT). Standalone Artemis should be more stable.